# Maximum number of distinct anagrams

Tags: c#

I'm doing an online class learning c# and the task i have been assigned is to make a program that give you the maximum possible number of anagrams without repeating from a string of letters. The code i made works for the examples like abc , aabc, but when a large string is entered for example abcdefghijklmnoqprstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnoqprstuvwxyz (alphabet twice) which is 52!, the result is 8.065829222532113E+26, where the result that the platform accepts is 1.20190046982384E+60.
I am thinking that Aparitii function formula is not ok but i have no ideea how to make it work properly.
It should be n1!*n2!*..nk! with n being the number of times a letter apeared and k the number of distict letters.

EDIT: the Aparitii function should find the factorial of the total distinct letters, for example: if a character is already present it should increment its factorial so at the end instead of aabc being factorial of 4! it should be 4! / 2!1!1!

```
using System;

public class anagram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        double rez1 = NrTotalLit(str);
        double rez2 = Aparitii(str);

        Console.WriteLine(rez1 / rez2);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static double NrTotalLit(string str)
    {
        double x = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= str.Length; i++)
        {
            x *= i;
        }
        return x;
    }

    static double Aparitii(string str)
    {
        double y = 1;
        double ap1 = 1;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < str.Length; j++)
            {
                if (str[i] == str[j])
                {
                    y = (ap1 *= j) + j;    // this formula might not be good    
                }
               
            }
        }
        return y ;      
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] you question with a description of what the function `Aparitii` should do ?

Comment: edited, hope it should explain a bit more

Comment: You should write the formula down (`4! / 2!1!1!`) and the values it should return (`24 / .....`)   Then you should debug your program, and check the values with the values you wrote before to see if they match your expectation.

Comment: the formula does that, the problem is that on larger strings, the platform i upload the program to does not valitate it for the string mentioned above becouse it gives a different value from what it expects. what i dont understand is why it works for small strings but for long ones it fails to give expected result

Comment: It seems like coindicence. Calculating from j does not make sense. You should rather rewrite it to make use of factorial function.

Comment: A simple way to start debugging would be with the string `aabb` what will be the expected output ?  (your current program gives `24/6=` 4, which I think should be `24/4` 
 ?)

Comment: @luuk, i see that you are right, but i have no ideea how to fix it, could you please tell me the correct formula i should use?

Comment: The correct formula should be in the assignment you got.

Answer (score -1):

I sorted the letters then worked out the factoral of each group of similar letters:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        double rez1 = Factoral(str.Length);
        double rez2 = Aparitii(str);

        Console.WriteLine(rez1 / rez2);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static double Factoral(int number)
    {
        double x = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
        {
            x *= i;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        return x;
    }

    static double Aparitii(string str)
    {
        var chrs = str.ToList();
        chrs.Sort();

        char previous = '\0';
        int last = -1;
        double y = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < chrs.Count; i++)
        {
            if (previous != chrs[i])
            {
                if (last > -1)
                {
                    y *= Factoral(i - last);
                }
                last = i;
                previous = chrs[i];
            }
        }
        if (last > -1)
        {
            y *= Factoral(chrs.Count - last);
        }
        return y;
    }
```